# integers in the text file

Tags: c++, file

so i need to write a program that produces the sum of all the whitespace-separated integers in a text file.
my code so far look like this

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    char text;
    ifstream txtfile;

    txtfile.open("intfile.txt");

    if (!txtfile) {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1);
    }

    while (txtfile >> text ){
        if (txtfile){
            sum = sum + text;
        }else if (txtfile.fail()){
            txtfile.clear();
            for (char text;txtfile>>text && !isdigit(text);)
                {};

        }
    }
    txtfile.close();
    cout << "Sum = " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

my text file look like this :

```
bears: 17 elephants 9 end
```

and my question is why my output is Sum = 2019. Also I don't have any errors so i don't know whats wrong.

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity to step through your code with your debugger. If you don't know how to use your debugger we could give you some tips.

Comment: Hint: `'b' + 'e' + 'a' + 'r' == 525`. If you know Python, you'll note that `sum(ord(c) for c in "bears:17elephants9end") == 2019`, i.e. you're summing the ASCII values of the characters in your file.

Comment: `while (txtfile >> text)` with `char text;` will read any character (with less chances to fail before end of file). However, a `char` is considered as integral type in C++. Hence, `sum = sum + text` will sum up all the (ASCII) values of read characters. (I didn't check but I bet this explains the outcome 2019.)

Comment: @Brian Ehem... I got 410: [**test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90c940f8a86fac09) ;-) `'b' + 'e' + 'a' + 'r' + 's' == 525`

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of creating objects with meaningful values rather than creating them with default values and immediately overwriting those values. In this case, that means changing `ifstream txtfile; txtfile.open("intfile.txt");` to `ifstream txtfile("intfile.txt");`. Also, you don't need to call `txtfile.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: Instead of reading into `char`, you could read into a `std::string`. Then you can try with [std::stoi()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) whether the string contains an integer. (In case of failing, it throws an exception which you should catch.) In case of success, add value to `sum`. [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e96340bd8a6d8df1)

Comment: What to you expect the output to be from the above file? 1 + 7 + 9 is 17 or 17 + 9 is 26. Basically do you want to read you input one digit at a time (which is what you are doing), or do you want to read it one number at a time (which makes more sense to me).

Comment: one number at a time sorry i forgot to mention it

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if the read in character is a number, since in c++ char type is implicitly converted to its ASCII value if you do numeric operations on it. 
Because of the difference between the ASCII value of a number and actually value you need to substract the first number '0' in the table.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
  int sum = 0;
  char text;
  std::ifstream txtfile;

  txtfile.open("../intfile.txt");

  if (!txtfile.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "Unable to open file" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  while (txtfile >> text ){
    if (txtfile && isdigit(text)){  // check if character is a digit
      sum += text - '0';            // take into account the ASCII table offset
    }else if (txtfile.fail()){
      txtfile.clear();
      for (char text;txtfile>>text && !isdigit(text);)
      {};

    }
  }
  txtfile.close();
  std::cout << "Sum = " << sum << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a bit off; the value stored in a `char` object is just a value. If you treat it like a character, that value can be interpreted as a character. If you treat it like a numeric value, it's a numeric value. It is not "implicitly converted" to its ASCII value (or to any other encoding). The value of `'0'` when encoded in ASCII is 0x30. `char x = '0';` sets the value of `x` to 0x30 (if your system uses ASCII). If you write `std::cout << x` you see `'0'` because the stream inserter (`<<`) treats the number 0x30 as the code for a character when you insert a `char`.

Comment: One further note: that comment "take into account the ASCII table offset" is correct on a system that uses ASCII. But more generally, on **all** systems, `text - '0'` will always give the  numeric value that the character in `text` represents. Not because it adjusts for "the ASCII table offset", but because it adjusts for the offset in **whatever encoding is being used**. +1.